# What is the difference between double and long double data type in c language

Tags: c

I am new in programming. When I run this code

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    double  i = 6.4;
    double  *ptr = &i;
    printf("The valu of ptr is %u\n",ptr);
    ptr++;
    printf("The valu of ptr is %u\n",ptr);
    ptr++;
    printf("The valu of ptr is %u\n",ptr);
    

    return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
The valu of ptr is 3904284976
The valu of ptr is 3904284984
The valu of ptr is 3904284992
```

from this it is clear that double type data needs 8 byte in  my memory.

But when I run this code

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    long double  i = 6.4;
    long double  *ptr = &i;
    printf("The valu of ptr is %u\n",ptr);
    ptr++;
    printf("The valu of ptr is %u\n",ptr);
    ptr++;
    printf("The valu of ptr is %u\n",ptr);
    

    return 0;
}
```

I get this output

```
The valu of ptr is 3519104768
The valu of ptr is 3519104784
The valu of ptr is 3519104800
```

From this it is seen that long double datatype needs 16 byte in memory.

What is the major difference between double and long double data type in c?

Comment: Your title does not match the question. In the title you say `long` which is a `long int`, while in the question you say `double`.

Comment: `long double` is dedicated to 80-bit-long FP type available on X86 machines. Generally it mean something *not worse* than double

Comment: On another note, to print a pointer using `printf` you must first of all use the correct format which is `%p`, and also cast the pointer to `void *`. Otherwise you really have *undefined behavior* (because of mismatching format specifier and argument type).

Comment: And finally for your problem: `double` is a double precision floating point type. `long double` have even higher precision (exact type depends on compiler and target system).

Comment: You need to clarify if you are asking about the difference between `long` and `long double` or the difference between `double` and `long double`. Because in case you are asking the former, your code examples are nonsensical.

Comment: On many platforms (e.g. Windows 64), `double` and `long double` are the same size. Although they are different types. On my fancy Solaris box, a `long double` is a quadruple precision type.

Comment: Note also that due to some obscure rules around pointer arithmetic, you can only increment `ptr` once. That's because it points to an object, which is understood to be an array of length one. Otherwise the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the major difference between double and long double data type in c?

Quoting from N1570 section "6.2.5 Types" this is what the C standard says:

> There are three real floating types, designated as float, double, and long
> double.The set of values of the type float is a subset of the set of values of the
> type double; the set of values of the type double is a subset of the set of values of the
> type long double

This means that `long double` is a floating point type having at least the same precision as the floating point type `double`.

So maybe `long double` is the same as `double`. Maybe it has better precision than `double`. The C standard only tells us that `long double` can't have worse precision than `double`.

This is further expanded in Annex E of the standard where the "minimum requirements" for double and long double is the same.

So the difference - if any - depends on your system.

Also notice that <float.h> on your system gives you information about the three floating point types on your system. For that please refer to the "5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating types <float.h>" of the standard - it's too much info to be pasted into this answer.

BTW:

Instead of using pointer values you could have printed the size, like:

```
printf("size of double %zu\n", sizeof(double));
printf("size of long double %zu\n", sizeof(long double));
```

If the sizes are different then it is very likely that `long double` has better precision than `double`.

Comment: Very good answer. "then it is very likely" has hidden depths too.